# How do input and print out specific values from list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to be able to input multiple last names and first name and also input multiple scores ,which is correlated/related to a specific last name and first name, in a list/s. i also need to be able to search for a name then print out the first name and last name with the score the person got.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Unfortunately, "I need" is not a question, it's a demand. Please show sample data and expected outputs as well as code you've attempted

Comment: We need to know what you've tried so far, how it didn't work, and where you searched in an attempt to solve this problem yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Build dictionary like:

```
data = {'record1':{'firstname':'abc', 'lastname':'xyz', 'score':20},
        'record2':{'firstname':'cde', 'lastname':'def', 'score':30},...}
```

Access using:

```
print data['record1']['firstname']
```

You can also use as:

```
print [ftype['firstname'] for f,ftype in data.iteritems() if f == 'record1' and 'firstname' in ftype]
```

The output will be **abc**

Answer (score 0):

It will good to use Python dictionary. If you want to make it in list then following code will helpful to you:

```
list1 = [["Akshay", "Gujar", 12], ["abc", "xyz", 45]]
find_name = "Akshay"
for i in range(len(list1)):
    if find_name in list1[i]:
        print("First Name:", list1[i][0])
        print("Last Name:", list1[i][1])
        print("Score:", list1[i][2])
```

First Name: Akshay

Last Name: Gujar

Score: 12

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you are trying to accomplish it will create the amount of dictionaries you need and then at the end you can search entries by name to retrieve the info

```
entries = int(input("How many entries? "))
lista = []
for i in range(entries):
    dicta = {}
    f_name = input("Enter First Name: ")
    dicta['First Name'] = f_name
    l_name = input("Enter Last Name: ")
    dicta['Last Name'] = l_name
    scores = int(input("How many scores? "))
    if scores == 0:
        dicta['Scores'] = []
    else:
        for i in range(scores):
            if 'Scores' not in dicta:
                score = int(input("Enter score: "))
                dicta['Scores'] = [score]
            else:
                score = int(input("Enter score: "))
                dicta['Scores'].append(score)
    lista.append(dicta)

while True:
    search = input("Enter a name: ")
    for i in lista:
        if i['First Name'] == search or i['Last Name'] == search:
            print(f"Name: {i['First Name']} {i['Last Name']}")
            print(f"Scores: {i['Scores']}")
```

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 noregex.py
> How many entries? 1
> Enter First Name: Vash
> Enter Last Name: Stampede
> How many scores? 2
> Enter score: 9000
> Enter score: 1
> Enter a name: Vash
> Name: Vash Stampede
> Scores: [9000, 1]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the below, iterating trough and formatting it:

```
data = {'record1':{'firstname':'abc', 'lastname':'xyz', 'score':20},
        'record2':{'firstname':'cde', 'lastname':'def', 'score':30}}
for k,v in data.items():
   print(', '.join(' : '.join(map(str,i)) for i in v.items()))
```

Output:

```
firstname : abc, lastname : xyz, score : 20
firstname : cde, lastname : def, score : 30
```